# Empty array supplied in AVS fastsimpleimport

Tags: magento-1.7, import, avs-fastsimpleimport

I am getting this Warning in my System.log:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in C:\htdocs\myrep\app\code\community\AvS\FastSimpleImport\Model\Import\Entity\Product.php on line 485
```

and for `line 508`.

So, these lines are `foreach` loops in the functions `setDropdownAttributes()` and `setMultiselectAttributes()`. Through debugging I found out that `$this->getDropdownAttributes()` (and `getMultiselectAttributes()`) return empty arrays, therefore supplying the `set` functions with empty arrays. And it returns an empty array because in here (in class `Varien_Object`):

```
public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
            case 'get' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $data;
```

the line `$data= $this->getData(...);` returns 0.

Although I get this warning, all my attributes, that are dropdown or multiselect, in the products that are being imported, are set with the correct values without any problems.

Another funny thing is that this happens only when I import on parts. This means that, f.e., I have 7 products to import in a single XML file - if I construct the importArray for all of them and import it at once - it's all fine, without warning. But if I try importing on every 3rd product, f.e., I get the warning (therefore 2 warnings). If I try doing it on every 2nd product - 3 warnings. And yet - the values are always being imported and set correctly. I really am confused.

Comment: magento version?

Comment: @FlorinelChis - 1.7.0.2

Comment: Are you using the latest version? 

This was added recently to fix some PHP5.4 warnings:
https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/commit/bb88e7e982040385f674dbb40574927508a61c4e

Comment: @PaulHachmang - wow, I am definitely not with the latest version, because I am missing like 50 lines of code from the class. Thanks, I will try updating and will post here whether that solved the problem. :)

Comment: You can post it as a self-answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul Hachmang suggested, I updated the `Import.php` in my `/app/code/community/AvS/FastSimpleImport/Model/` and I got rid of the annoying warning. [Here's a link to the GitHub commit with the last changes.](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/commit/bb88e7e982040385f674dbb40574927508a61c4e)

Comment: Accept it so it is marked as solved :)